# How to read ATFX data?

Tags: python, xml, file, measurement

I have a set of measurement data in .atfx format. I know it is possible to read this data with ArtemiS SUITE, but I would need to make some post processing in python. I tried to look into the files, but as I see, atfx is a header file (with an xml structure) that points to binary files, so I'm not sure how I could write a python script to decode that, or if it is possible at all.

Is there a way to open ATFX files in python or is there a workaround?

Comment: Please, take some time to read [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

ATFX files should follow the standards set by ASAM.  However, it's a newer format, and many tools haven't adopted it yet.  Try using the asammdf module to read the binary (dat) files.

[Source](https://www.asam.net/standards/detail/ods/wiki/#TechnicalContent)

Comment: As per this link it is not supported in asammdf https://github.com/danielhrisca/asammdf/issues/583